# Position 2 items side by side fluid/responsive (unknown width)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a React project at work (our company offered us Full-Stack positions).

I have a wrapper `div` inside which there are 2 other `divs`.

Here is what the divs do:

1. `Left Div` - (Text `span`, also contains ellipsis and hidden overflow, variable `div` width) hence the width of the parent `div` has to fit the text content.
2. `Right Div` - (Sorting Icon), The sorting icon has to be stuck to the right side of the left `div` and fill the rest of the space of the `parent div`, though the icon has to stick beside the header text at all times [Zoom friendly].

Here is an image of what I would like:
[image]

And here is what I have:
[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
return (
    <>
        <div className={classes.headerWithSort}>
            <span>{col.label}</span>
            {canSort ? (
                <div>{sortIcon}</div>
            ) : null}
        </div>
    </>
);
```

And here is my JSX/CSS:

```
headerWithSort: {
    position: 'relative',
    border: '1px dashed black',
    height: 'inherit',
    width: 'inherit',
    '& > span': {
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        lineHeight: '3.29rem',
        border: '1px dashed green',
        float: 'left'
    },
    '& > div': {
        border: '1px dashed red',   
        overflow: 'hidden'
    },
    '& > *': {
        height: 'inherit'
    }
},
```

[Edit] - Another example of what I would like:
[image]

I have been stuck on this for quite some time, would appreciate any kind of help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding Bootstrap CDN's to your project as such:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"> 
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
```

Then you can Create 2 columns (left one smaller and right one larger) and insert your content in them as such:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-5">
     <h3>Elipses text</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-7">
     <h3>icon</h3>
     <img/>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap columns are always divided in 12 so if you add the col numbers together you should get 12, if you want the columns to be the same size and half the page use "col-sm-6" for both. This is very useful for your zooming scenario, coupled with Media queries you can't go wrong.

Getting to know Bootstrap is really one of the greatest ways to learn responsive and quick web design.

Comment: Hey Adriaan, sadly it's not under my privilege to add project dependencies, we use Material-UI and our own CSS, so if you have a native CSS way of doing this then please do tell.

Comment: Hey Alex, you can still download the Bootstrap CSS files and open them in visual studio code to see how they are doing the column classes then implement your own version based on theirs. Hope this helps.